# Character-set of SSH keys (safe delimiter for using sed with public keys)

Tags: ssh, sed

I am using `sed` to replace a placeholder in a script with my public ssh key. The character `/` is definitely present in some SSH keys, how can I find out which character I can use as delimiter for `sed`?

I am looking for an answer of either the set of all characters that can be part of the string generated by `ssh-keygen`, or which characters are guaranteed not to.

Comment: ssh key data is base64 encoded...so, just look up the valid character set for base64 encoding. I think there's an RFC for that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The public key in opnessh format is `base64-encoded` as mentioned for example in the manual page for `sshd`. Therefore you can use any character that is not in the list of [base64 characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Design). The `/` is there but for example `|` can be used safely (though in the comment section can be anything).

Comment: Just to complete, judging from wikipedia, everything outside `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `/`, `+`, and `=` should be fine, if it does not appear in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

For information, from the `info sed`, section 3.5:

> The '/' characters may be uniformly replaced by any other single character within any given 's' command.
>
> The '/' character (or whatever other character is used in its stead) can
>   appear in the REGEXP or REPLACEMENT only if it is preceded by a '\'
>   character.

So you can chose any suitable character that doesn't appear in your input data.

Comment: The question was more like, which would be suitable character that is guaranteed not to appear in my input data (ssh keys)? Not how do I use a different delimiter in `sed`.